# Suppress "integral does not converge" error message

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

Is there a way to suppress this error message and beep?

Comment: Take a look at`Quiet`.

Comment: Turn the message [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html): `Off[Integrate::idiv]`

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to suppress the specific message, and let others pass.

[image]

code:

```
ClearAll[x, a]
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"};
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions","KernelMessageAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook", "Beep"};
```

And now

```
Quiet[Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0,Infinity}], {Integrate::idiv}]
```